# Podman Hue Container doesn't with Hadoop 3 ecosystem

Tags: kerberos, hue, podman, hadoop3

I have an issue and really don't know what to do with it.
So all Hadoop 3 components have been deployed on a few hosts with kerberos.
Hue is working on podman container, which is stored on the one of few hosts in hadoop cluster.
Keytab was generated fot technical user for hue.

hue.ini:

```
[desktop]
# Webserver listens on this address and port
http_host=0.0.0.0
http_port=8888
time_zone=Europe/Warsaw

[database]
engine=django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
host=ip
port=port
user=hue
password=password
name=hue

[users]
default_user_group=hue
create_users_on_login=true

[kerberos]
# Path to Hue's Kerberos keytab file
hue_keytab=/etc/security/keytabs/keytab_name.keytab
# Kerberos principal name for Hue
hue_principal=principal (which is technical username)
# add kinit path for non root users
kinit_path=/usr/kerberos/bin/kinit

[beeswax]
# If Kerberos security is enabled, use fully qualified domain name (FQDN)
hive_server_host=hive_server
# Hive configuration directory, where hive-site.xml is located
hive_conf_dir=/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
#Hive server port
hive_server_port=10000
```

When the Hue works, it gives me below error:
Bad status: 3 (b'Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN') (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException("Bad status: 3 (b'Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN')")

In hive-site.xml, which is in container as well, is correctly defined Kerberos mechanism.

Hope, somebody knows the answer.
Thanks in advance !